# NetworkManager refuses to follow symlinks to another filesystem

Tags: rhel, networkmanager, readonly

We're building a pseudo-embedded system, where we're trying to replace Centos7.x with RHEL9.x (or AlmaLinux9.x).

CentOS7.x used config files as scripts in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` but RHEL9.x prefers ini-style files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. So far all's well. The syntax is different, but not wildly impenetrable.

However - we want to keep the rootfs read-only, and used to have symlinks to another read/write partition for these configuration files, and that's something that NetworkManager  doesn't seem to like. (It will for example patch `/etc/resolv.conf` at the slightest provocation, and refuses to follow symlinks for the `.nmconnection` files.)

Is there a way to use NetworkManager with a Read-Only rootfs? I don't mind having static symlinks for e.g. `/etc/NetworkManager` and `/etc/resolv.conf` to a writable filesystem - but simply replacing the files with symlinks doesn't seem to work.

**/etc/resolv.conf**

[Edited to add:]
One reason why replacing e.g. `/etc/resolv.conf` with a symlink doesn't work is that NetworkManager at startup does *not* try to edit this file, but instead creates another file in `/etc/` and then renames it. Is there a way to tell NetworkManager not to do that?

[Further edit:]
It looks very much like [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=214460), that was reported in 2006. It looks like it was never resolved.

**/etc/NetworkManager/**

Setting this to a symlink to a folder on another partition works - *If SELinux is disabled*. If I enable SELinux, it fails.

Comment: What if you make `/etc/NetworkManager` a symlink to an alternative directory, rather than the individual files?

Comment: About SELinux: you can try using [`semanage fcontext -a -e`](https://manpages.debian.org/policycoreutils-python-utils/semanage-fcontext.8#e) (see [examples](https://manpages.debian.org/policycoreutils-python-utils/semanage-fcontext.8#EXAMPLE)) to get it working as usual. Requires to run restorecon at the end.